# Rails simple form, input type date not showing all years (just 11)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, simple-form

I have a SimpleForm for a User, with birthday as an attribute:

```
t.date "birthday"
```

I generate a SimpleForm:

```
<%= f.input :birthday %>
```

Rails generates the 3 inputs for day, month and year:

[image]

But the years just go from 2014 until 2024.

Is this the default behaviour now? I've tried to add myself the collection of years, but I don't have a normal input, I have a date input, which is separated into 3 by Rails, that's why I don't know how to solve the problem.

Can somebody help me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure about the defaults, but simple_form allow customizing year range (which is in [their README](https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form), btw)

```
  <%= f.input :date_of_birth, as: :date, start_year: Date.today.year - 90,
                              end_year: Date.today.year - 12, discard_day: true,
                              order: [:month, :year] %>
```